# atleast two balls identical in 5 bags

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

There are five bags each containing identical sets of ten distinct chocolates. One chocolate is picked from each bag.

The probability that at least two chocolates are identical is?

I know the solution can be arrived by using 1-(none ball is picked is same) like this P(No two chocolates are identical) = $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 = 30240$
so P(no two chocolates are identical) $ = \dfrac{30240}{100000} = 0.3024$

P(At least two chocolates are identical) = $ 1$ – P(No two chocolates are identical)

$ = 1 – 0.3024 = 0.6976$

But I used this approach
probability at least $2$ bags have identical chocolates is equal to = probability of two exactly two bag having same chocolates + probability of exactly three bag having same chocolates +probability of exactly four bags having same chocolates + probability of five bags have identical chocolates.

Now I have calculated two bag having same chocolates is calculate as

No. of ways of choosing two bags $C(5,2)$ and the these two bags have same chocolates rest have different chocolates so each $C(5,2)$ will have $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7$ (basically reducing number of bags having distinct chocolates to 4 by grouping pair )

So number of bags having exactly two identical chocolates is $ \displaystyle {5 \choose 2} \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 = 50400$

Similarly number of bags having exactly three identical chocolates $ \displaystyle {5 \choose 3} \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 = 7200$

Similarly number of bags having exactly four identical chocolates $ \displaystyle {5 \choose 3} \cdot 10 \cdot 9 = 450$

Similarly number of bags having exactly five identical chocolates = $ \displaystyle {5 \choose 5} \cdot 10 = 10$

Total $58060$

out of total configuration $10 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 =100000$

So answer becomes $ \dfrac {58060}{100000} =0.5806$

I know I am missing something but what can you please help

Comment: Please use mathjax. Here is a basic tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$58060$ counts all outcomes where there is an identical chocolate drawn from two or more bags and we draw different chocolates from all remaining bags. But you have not counted outcomes where there are *two sets* of identical chocolates drawn:

case $1$: Out of $5$ bags, we draw an identical chocolate from two bags and another identical chocolate from another two bags.

case $2$: Out of $5$ bags, we draw an identical chocolate from two bags and another identical chocolate from remaining three bags.

Case $1$: Choose $3$ chocolate types, choose which $2$ repeat and then arrange $5$ chocolates to be drawn from $5$ bags.

$ \displaystyle {10 \choose 3} {3 \choose 2} \cdot \frac{5!}{2! ~ 2!} = 10800$

Case $2$: Choose $2$ chocolate types, choose which type we have three chocolates of and then arrange $5$ chocolates to be drawn from $5$ bags.

$ \displaystyle {10 \choose 2} {2 \choose 1} \cdot \frac{5!}{3! ~ 2!} = 900$

So the desired probability is

$ \displaystyle = \frac{58060 + 10800 + 900}{10^5} = 0.6976$

Comment: hello I am still not getting how you calculated case 1 and case 2 as i am new to combinations and permutation

Comment: @NikhilVidhani that's alright. Let's take case $1$ first. Can you tell me till what point you understand. I will explain.

Comment: What you are doing is fine but you are double counting. You are choosing $2$ out of $5$ and then $2$ out of $3$. That orders the types of chocolates that are repeating and then when you do $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8$, you order them again.

Comment: I will explain the approach in my answer. Case1: there are two chocolates of one type and two chocolates of another type and one chocolate of third type. In total there are $10$ types of chocolates. So let's choose $3$ types first. That is given by ${10 \choose 3}$. Now from the chosen $3$ types, we need to decide of which two types, there will be two chocolates each. That is $3 \choose 2$. Let's say we chose two chocolates each of types $T1$ and $T2$ and one of type $T3$. So we have $\{T1, T1, T2, T2, T3\}$. Now we assign them to different bags by permuting.

Comment: I am getting your point and i know that is correct point but again I not getting double counting point in my way of solution what I am doing is choosing 2 bags out of five and out 3 bags more 2 bags (in case 1) this makes 2 pairs for {B1 B5} and {B2 B4 } remaining B5 so they are kind of three bags to be filled with 10 chocolates so 10 *9*8 that's my way of thinking and I am not able to find any counter example by which I have double counted It would be helpful if you can tell what is wrong in this method that is how I am double counting by providing a example

Comment: Say as part of $5C2$, you choose $\{B1, B5\}$ and then as part of $3C2$, you choose $\{B2, B4\}$. But as part of $5C2$, you will have a selection where you would choose $\{B2, B4\}$ and as part of $3C2$, $\{B1, B5\}$. Do you see the double counting?